# Recover an ABS pump for a Ford Ranger 95

Tags: ford, abs, ranger

The Ranger STX 95 activates the ABS pump on slow speeds, below 10km/h, but does not on higher speeds. It also works as expected on loose or wet soil.

All sensors were replaced. A trusted mechanic said that the problem is probably on the ABS pump, but the current pump does not show any errors on the raster sensor, although the speed on the sensors, when driving the truck, are stuck at 0 for the front sensors and 94 km/h on the back sensor.

Is there something that can be fixed in the pump itself to stop this incorrect activation?

Comment: When you state it activates at low speeds and not at high speeds, are you saying at high speeds the wheels just lock up?

Comment: Sorry, no. I mean that at high speeds the wheels turn fine and the ABS only activates when expected, like on water, dirt, etc.

Comment: How hard have you pressed the brake pedal while going at higher speeds? I've found unless you pretty much stand on the brakes, the ABS won't kick in because the wheels are still turning.

Comment: I have to hard press on high velocities, as expected. On low speeds, a simple touch on the break pedal can make the ABS activate.